# Can't make mosquitto-auth-plug

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, libmosquitto

[image]

Not sure if you can read the picture....

/bin/ld: cannot find -lmosquitto

is the error.

I'm using centos 7

mosquitto-auth-plug config file has been updated with mosquitto src and openssl install directory and they are correct.

My previous error was mysql_config not found which I was able to fix by installing libmysqlclient-devel

mysql is installed and working fine

Let me know if you can help
Thanks

Comment: Nothing but a down vote.  I have been using linux for about 2 days now and I am a newbie.  it appears the library is missing I have searched for it.  The only library I can fine is mosquitto.h and I have that.  This has to be done so I will just keep trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem copy mosquitto.so.1 from usr/lib64 to your mosquitto source direcrory/lib as mosquitto.so

That will fix the problem I had here.

then add -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl to the LDFLAG in the Makefile